# what is "tcpConnState.0.0.0.0.12000.0.0.0.0.0"?

Tags: linux, networking, snmpd

I found below snmpget command in bash script which is used to check the remote server status; is the remote server up or down.
Command is

```
snmpget $1 tcpConnState.0.0.0.0.12000.0.0.0.0.0 | grep listen | wc -l
```

here `$1` is the hostname of remote server. Whenever I try to execute the command its showing below error

```
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
snmpget: No securityName specified (Sub-id not found: (top) -> tcpConnState)
0
```

Any changes required in the snmpd configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

`tcpConnState` is part of the `TCP-MIB` and retrieves information on active tcp connections on the remote host (similar to the information available from `netstat`). The first five digits are the server's local address & port for the tcp connection, and the last five are the remote address and port.

For example an active ssh connection looks as follows, with `a.b.c.d` as the server and `w.x.y.z` as the client

```
TCP-MIB::tcpConnState.a.b.c.d.22.w.x.y.z.62612 = INTEGER: established(5)
```

In this case it is looking for a tcp socket from `0.0.0.0` (any local address) port 12000, to remote host `0.0.0.0` port 0 - which is what a listening socket would usually show up as (assuming it's not bound to a specific local IP address). So in short it's checking if there's something listening on port 12000 on the snmp target.

It's possible that the remote host doesn't support the `tcpConnState` operation, or it's not exposed.

I would try an `snmpwalk` on the remote host first to see if the `tcpConnState` tree appears. If it's something like a Linux box that's running the standard snmpd daemon it should support this so it may be disabled in configuration.